# Скрол в глубину

Tags: javascript, события, scrollbar

Подскажите плз есть ли какой либо способ сделать скрол не по у координатах а по z и при етом не использовать канвас? проблема в том что если нету полос прокрутки то и ивент onscroll не вызывается и соответственно я не могу ничего делать, а именно хочу делать зум елементам на странице.

Comment: `transform: scale(value)`;

Comment: можно обрабатывать событие `wheel` вроде бы

Comment: А не проще увеличивать сам элемент, а на страницу вешать событие wheel?

Comment: спасибо большое wheel  то что надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать событие `wheel`

```js
var zoom = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.zoom').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
            zoom += 0.1;
        } else {
            zoom -= 0.1;
        }
        $(this).css('transform', 'scale('+ zoom +')');
    });
});
```

```css
.zoom {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="zoom"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, ребята из коментов правы, скрол ивент только по факту а за wheel я совсем забыл он же срабатывает на прокрутку колеса мышки.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/492467)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, никто не написал просто ответ, они все предлагали в комментарии

Answer (score 0):

Вот Вам пример

```js
let box = document.querySelector('div')

window.addEventListener('wheel', evt => {
  if (Math.sign(evt.deltaY) === 1) {
    box.style.transform = `scale(${+box.style.transform.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'') - 1})`
  } else {
    box.style.transform = `scale(${+box.style.transform.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'') + 1})`
  }
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div style="transform: scale(1)"></div>
```